# Time of working generating hash with sha2

Tags: sha256

It is fragment of pseudocode algorithm SHA2 from wikipedia:

```
break message into 512-bit chunks
for each chunk
    create a 64-entry message schedule array w[0..63] of 32-bit words
```

For me, it means that time of working SHA2 algorithm depends on size of input word.   So the more input word is, the longer time of working SHA2 is.

Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true, though the timing differences between two short messages (e.g. 100 and 1000 bytes) are negligible. Computing the SHA256 hash of a gigabyte of data understandably takes much longer than computing the SHA256 hash of a few hundred bytes.